# Unable to run gqlgen generate due to missing go.sum entry for module

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

I'm following the tutorial at https://blog.logrocket.com/gqlgen-build-faster-graphql-server/ and `gqlgen init` runs fine.

Following the guide, I'm trying to generate new schemas and resolvers (adding the Dog type) using `go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate`, but the command instantly fails.

Example:

```
go run github.com/99designs/gqlgen generate
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/main.go:20:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package github.com/urfave/cli/v2 (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/codegen/field.go:16:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/text/cases (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen@v0.17.26
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/codegen/field.go:17:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/text/language (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen@v0.17.26
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/internal/imports/prune.go:15:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/go/ast/astutil (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports@v0.17.26
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/internal/code/packages.go:11:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/go/packages (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen/config); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/codegen/config@v0.17.26
../../../go/pkg/mod/github.com/99designs/gqlgen@v0.17.26/internal/imports/prune.go:16:2: missing go.sum entry for module providing package golang.org/x/tools/imports (imported by github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports); to add:
    go get github.com/99designs/gqlgen/internal/imports@v0.17.26
```

So I run all of these `go get` for those missing modules in that order, and try to re-run `generate` and it works! Nice!

But when I try to run `generate` again the very next entered command, the same command fails with the same errors and missing packages.

Why are all those imports missing by initial setup, then deleted and why isn't this working out of the box?

Comment: did you try `go mod tidy` ?

Comment: The 99designs solution needs you to explicitly create a `tools.go` file, as written below, before `go mod tidy` is any helpful. I ran it several times before finding this solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the (stupid) answer is to follow the guide at the `gqlgen` [github repo](https://github.com/99designs/gqlgen) and create a separate `tools.go` file, like so:

*Add github.com/99designs/gqlgen to your project's tools.go*

`printf '// +build tools\npackage tools\nimport (_ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen"\n _ "github.com/99designs/gqlgen/graphql/introspection")' | gofmt > tools.go`

And then do a final `go mod tidy`.

The very "opinionated" conclusion from me (the OP) is that this shouldn't be a thing since the `init` command works just fine after the initial import. But hey.. it is what it is.